# Fickle IE Issues with Height 100%

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to set the height to 100% in the viewport for Internet Explorer. As you might imagine, the following code works everywhere else:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
 font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
 font-size: 13px; 
 background-color:#E8E8E8;
 background:url(/images/background.png) repeat-x;
}

#wrap {
 margin:0 auto;
 width: 935px; /*  Change to desired width :)  */
 min-height: 100%;
 background:url(/images/content.png)repeat-y;
}

#main {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 112px;
}  /* must be same height as the footer */
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor question, but the real problem here is that the repeated image in the wrap isn't repeating in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Unless you provide your HTML it will be impossible to guess what you have in mind.

Comment: Try applying border to your wrap to see the actual size of the div. Perhaps it's collapsed.

Comment: It is not collapsed. The background just isn't repeating properly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this HTML structure:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If so add min-height to the `wrap` div:

```
#wrap
{
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Note that this technique does not work on older IEs (when exactly it stops working below IE7 I am not sure) and it has unpredictable issue with Opera which has its own opinion on how to interpret `height` and `min-height` instructions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply. Changing it did not fix the issue I am having. And yes, that is my HTML structure.